# How to replace occurences of groups with NSRegularExpression option for String?

Tags: ios, swift, nsregularexpression

I simply created extension:

```
extension String {
    var formattedPhoneNumber: String {
        return replacingOccurrences(of: "^(+48)([0-9]{3})([0-9]{3})([0-9]{3})$", with: "$0 $1 $2 $3", options: .regularExpression)
    }
}
```

And trying to use it like this:

```
let formattedNumber = "+48123456789".formattedPhoneNumber
```

but it returns `+48123456789` instead of `+48 123 456 789`. Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`+` in regex means "one or more times", but you mean `+` literally, so you need to escape it. Without escaping it, the regex doesn't match, so your string is left unchanged. Also, group 0 refers to the whole match, not the things surrounded by the first pair of parentheses. That's group 1.

```
extension String {
    var formattedPhoneNumber: String {
        return replacingOccurrences(of: "^(\\+48)([0-9]{3})([0-9]{3})([0-9]{3})$", with: "$1 $2 $3 $4", options: .regularExpression)
    }
}
```